# LinkButton does not fire postback

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I have a linkbutton that somehow does not give a postback when clicked. Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#divTabs').tabs({
            show: function () {
                var sel = $('#divTabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
                $('#<%= hfLastTab.ClientID %>').val(sel);
            },
            selected: '<%= hfLastTab.Value %>'
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="divTabs">
    <ul>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar1" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink1" runat="server" OnClick="TabLink1_Click" >&nbsp;Link1&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar2" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink2" runat="server" OnClick="TabLink2_Click">&nbsp;Link2&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar3" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink3" runat="server" OnClick="TabLink3_Click">&nbsp;Link3&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>
    ....
</div>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void TabLink1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SelectTopBar();
    SetSelectTab("TabBar1");
}

protected void TabLink2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SelectTopBar();
    SetSelectTab("TabBar2");
}

protected void TabLink3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SelectTopBar();
    SetSelectTab("TabBar3");
}
```

I tried putting the breakpoint in the codebehind and it does not hit. The page is not refreshed as well. If I use `<asp:Button>`, then it will do the submit and everything seems to be fine.
I also tried to see whether there are more than one `<form>` tags, but there is not.
I also make sure that in the aspx page, those click event are tied.

[EDIT]: The link button is located inside a jquery tab. So instead of using the ordinary `<a href...` as in the jquery example which does not do any postback, I used asp linkbutton and want the postback.

Any idea?

Comment: Does the click event not fire for all three of them or just for `TabLink1`?

Comment: @ekad All of them do not work

Comment: Or maybe those three linkbuttons are outside of `<form>` tag?

Comment: @ekad I've rebuilt the project, and it is the same.. Those three linkbuttons are inside the form tag.

Comment: It also does not work :(

Comment: I've added more info.. The link buttons are located inside the jquery tab.. Don't know whether it matters or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some workaround. I defined another linkbutton outside the `<div id="divTabs">`, and the linkbutton inside `<div id="divTabs">` will call the outer linkbutton. So the code becomes like

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="TabLink1_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="TabLink2_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" OnClick="TabLink3_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>

<div id="divTabs">
    <ul>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar1" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink1" runat="server">&nbsp;Link1&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar2" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink2" runat="server">&nbsp;Link2&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar3" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink3" runat="server">&nbsp;Link3&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>
    ....
</div>
```

In the code behind, inside the `Page_Load` function

```
TabLink1.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('" + LinkButton1.ClientID + "').click();";
TabLink2.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('" + LinkButton2.ClientID + "').click();";
TabLink3.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('" + LinkButton3.ClientID + "').click();";
```

I'm guessing the jQuery library might have some impact such that the link does not call a postback, so I'm using the workaround above.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is looking.  I had the same problem with the LinkButton OnClick event not firing, and fixed it by simply using "OnCommand=" instead of "OnClick=".

Comment: Didn't do anything for me, same behaviour

Comment: Thanks! I was using an AddHandler in VB.Net this is what fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including a responseredirect as the last line of each event like in the below example?

```
  protected void TabLink1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   SelectTopBar();
   SetSelectTab("TabBar1");
   Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);


}
```

Comment: Tried that but does not work. I put the breakpoint at the beginning of the function (SelectTopBar), and it is not called. So the Response.Redirect will not be called as well.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#divTabs').tabs({
            show: function () {
                var sel = $('#divTabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
                $('#<%= hfLastTab.ClientID %>').val(sel);
            },
            selected: '<%= hfLastTab.Value %>'
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="divTabs">
    <ul>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar1" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink1" CauseValidation="false" runat="server" OnClick="TabLink1_Click" >&nbsp;Link1&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar2" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink2" runat="server" CauseValidation="false" OnClick="TabLink2_Click">&nbsp;Link2&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li runat="server" id="TabBar3" ><asp:LinkButton ID="TabLink3" runat="server" CauseValidation="false" OnClick="TabLink3_Click">&nbsp;Link3&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>
    ....
</div>
```

Use CausesValidation="false"

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's looking for a solution that actually works, it's because you're fiddling with javascript somehow and that's overriding the .NET postback behaviour.

In my case it was simply using Bootstrap and adding the `data-toggle="buttons"` e.markup to the button group like:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
```

That was recognized by Bootstrap JavaScript because it needs to watch these buttons in the group to be able to display their toggle status correctly (i.e. adding/removing the "active" class to/from children).

Solution: removed that data-toggle and implemented the toggle status highlighting with some C# inline code.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is .NET framework's fault,
for me `__doPostBack` did not work in all pages because I compiled my project with a newer version of Visual studio. I changed "Target framework" from "*.NET framework 4.0*" to "*.NET framework 3.0*", and after that rebuild project and it has worked.